# Optional chaining in typescript doesn't work for me in webstorm

Tags: typescript

I'm getting this error message:

[image]

I can't find anything about chaining in webstorm config so here are my config:

Angular verion: 8

Webstorm: 2020.3

typescript version 4.0.2

in package.json:

```
    "typescript": "^4.0.3",
    ...
    "ts-node": "^7.0.1",
    "tslint": "^5.20.1",
    "tslint-config-prettier": "^1.18.0",
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": [ "es2017" ],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

tslint.json:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "member-access": true,
    "no-console": false,
    "ordered-imports": false,
    "one-variable-per-declaration": false,
    "indent": [true, "spaces", 2],
    "no-empty": false,
    "object-literal-sort-keys": false,
    "no-submodule-imports": false,
    "member-ordering": false,
    "no-var-requires": false
  },
  "extends": [
    "tslint:latest",
    "tslint-config-prettier"
  ]
}
```

Comment: What is your version of TypeScript?

Comment: my typescript verion is 4.0.2